# Using Riemann integrals to find limits

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, riemann-integration

Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{n+k}}$$

I can't seem to remove the $\frac{1}{n}$ term in order to use the riemann integral any help?

Comment: Two different sums, one in numerator and the other one un denominator? That's weird...are you sure that's right? Also, shouldn't it be $\;n^2+k^2\;$ or something like that inside the denominator's square root?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let me introduce some terms $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{n+k}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}}{\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{n+k}{n}}}  $$

Comment: Oh so are we supposed to calculate two riemann integrals in this case

Comment: That is my first intuition when I first look at the question.

Comment: $$\ldots = \frac{\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\,dx}{\int_1^2\sqrt{x}\,dx}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}+1}{7}.$$